# How to play a sound in java from the millisecond X

Tags: java, audio, milliseconds

I have a problem, I wanna play a sound (or music file) for example from the second 10 to the 12, it is possible to make an function like soundObject.play(10000,12000); ?
actually i'm testing sound classes but I only can play, stop and loop

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should take a loo at following. [Playing Back Audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html)

Comment: You should use thread to control the timer sleep for your app.

Comment: It's possible, but I highly suggest you just trim the audio file

Comment: The application I'm thinking to do will use 100 songs, and for each song 5 pieces of audio with 2 seconds. This is 500 trims, too much work :S that is why I need to find a method to play from a point

Comment: clip was referenced in the link by @Smit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer, this is the code I used to
play the 3-5 seconds

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class SoundClipTest{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
       URL myURL= ClassLoader.getSystemResource("abesti.wav");
       AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(myURL);
       Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
       clip.open(audio);
       clip.setMicrosecondPosition(3000000);
       clip.start();
       try {
        Thread.sleep(2000); //in milliseconds
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       clip.stop();
   }
}
```